# if $T$ is a stopping time, $X_T$ is $\mathcal F_T$ measurable. Proof with characteristic functions

Tags: probability-theory, stopping-times

I'd like to prove that if $T$ is a stopping time, $X_T$ is $\mathcal F_T$ measurable.

I know the set theory argument, but I thought that writting (as recommanded here : [How to show that a stopped process $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}$ measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/218225/how-to-show-that-a-stopped-process-x-t-is-mathcalf-measurable) ) :

$$
X_T=\sum_n\mathbf 1_{T=n}\cdot X_n
$$
would make the proof simplier.

However I don't know how to conclude. My problem is that I don't know what to do with the $X_n$, which are $\mathcal F_n$ measurable, but possibly not $\mathcal F_T$ measurable. How can I do that ?

Comment: What is wrong with @Did's answer? It seems to follow along the lines of what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Notice that I am trying to prove that $X_T$ is $F_T$ measurable. $X_n$ is not $F_T$ measurable for all $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $B$ be any Borel set, then $$\{X_T \in B\} \cap \{T \leq k\} = \bigcup_{n=0}^k \{X_T \in B\} \cap \{T=n\} = \bigcup_{n=0}^k \{X_n \in B\} \cap \{T=n\} \in \mathcal{F}_k,$$ and so $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable.

Alternatively you can use the following small lemma which follows directly from the definition of $\mathcal{F}_T$.

> A random variable $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$ measurable if, and only if, $Y 1_{\{T \leq k\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$ measurable for each $k \geq 0$.

Since (according to the identity from the body of your question) $$X_T 1_{\{T\leq k\}} = \sum_{n=0}^k X_n 1_{\{T=n\}},$$ it follows that $X_T 1_{\{T \leq k\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable and so $X_T$ is $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable.

Comment: sorry, why is $X_T 1_{\{T \leq k\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable  ? And why does it imply beeing $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable? As I mentionned in my original post, saying $\mathcal{F}_k \subset \mathcal{F}_T$ is false. Actually, that was the main point I couldn't figure out and thus conclude on the proof. If you can detail that it would be great.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Did you try to prove the lemma which I stated in my answer? Re your first question: Note that $X_n 1_{\{T=n\}}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$-measurable, hence $F_k$-measurable for $k \geq n$, and so $X_T 1_{\{T \leq k\}} = \sum_{n=0}^k X_n 1_{\{T=n\}}$ is $F_k$-measurable.

Comment: you're right, I was simply missing your lemma. It is a cool one in fact, cheers

Comment: How do we show $Y1_{T=k}$ is$F_k$ measurable in your lemma

Comment: @badatmath Set $Z:=Y 1_{\{T \leq k\}}$ for an $\mathcal{F}_T$-measurable random variable $Y$, then $$\{Z \in B\} = \{Y \in B\} \cap \{T \leq k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k$$ if $0 \notin B$ and $$\{Z \in B\} = \big( \{Y \in B\} \cap \{T \leq k\} \big) \cup \{T>k\} \in \mathcal{F}_k$$ if $0 \in B$. Hence, $Z$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable

Comment: How do we do it for $Y1_{T=k}$ though

Comment: @badatmath $Y 1_{T=k} = Y 1_{T \leq k} -Y 1_{T \leq k-1}$ is $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable as it is the difference of $\mathcal{F}_k$-measurable random variables.